# apt-get install not install dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, xorg, dependencies

I faced a really weird issue recently in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Here are the steps:

1. I have a deb package called `test.deb` which has dependency on `xorg-dev`
2. Then I tried to install this deb package by `sudo apt-get install test`
3. All dependencies are installed except for xorg-dev. The error is `Depends: xorg-dev but it is not going to be installed`
4. I ran this next `sudo apt-get install xorg-dev`
5. xorg-dev got installed successfully

My question is apt-get should be able to install all dependencies available. Since xorg-dev is available, why it is not getting installed at first time?

Comment: are you sure the version you installed and the version requested by test.deb are the same?

Comment: hi, there is no version restrictions on dependencies, so could be any version.

Comment: Maybe it's worth trying adding a version? I'm not into packaging, but from the few debs I compiled, I seem to remember I always used a version (eg: >= 7.6)

Comment: thanks! i tried using this version xorg-dev >=1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1, but still not working.